# Specify separator on jooq groupConcatDistinct method

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Is there a way to specify a custom separator for the method `groupConcatDistinct` in JOOQ? There is a second parameter for the method `groupConcat` but this one returns multiple times the same values, which I don't want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I found the answer, with `groupConcatDistinct` the separator is chained and not a parameter. Like this `groupConcatDistinct(...).separator(", ")`

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is just an oversight in API design. I've created a feature request here:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7956

As always when working with jOOQ and you encounter a missing feature, you can resort to using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/). E.g.

```java
Field<String> f = DSL.field(
    "group_concat(distinct {0}, ', ')", 
    SQLDataType.VARCHAR, 
    MY_COLUMN
);
```